# jqgrid treegrid how to reload data?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, treegrid

I know how to reload normal jqgrid table. I used the same method to reload treegrid, but it doesn't work.

The usual method to reload jqgrid:

```
$jqGrid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{ 
        url:path+"/admin/demo/getLogsGridJson.do", 
        postData:{'aaa':111,'bbb':222}, //
        page:1 
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

This way I can again request and refresh data.  But with treegrid it doesn't work.

How to reload treegrid to use new postData or new url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reload the jqGrid TreeGrid with new post data you will need to set treedattype to json like this

```
$jqGrid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{ 
    url:path+"/admin/demo/getLogsGridJson.do", 
    postData:{'aaa':111,'bbb':222}, //
    page:1,
    treedatatype : 'json'
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

More about why is this you can read in [Guriddo jqGrid Documenatation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/treegrid/#limitations)
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset `treeANode` parameter of TreeGrid to `-1`. You can replace unneeded setting of `page:1` to `treeANode:-1`. You can consider to add `data: [], _index: {}` to the options of `setGridParam` to improve the performance if you loaded previously large set of data.